# How can I adjust the size of a row in grid in Vaadin 13?

Tags: vaadin

I have a Details component in a Grid that can expand and show a button. When I click it, it does expand but you cannot see the button unless you click on that row. How can I make that row in a grid bigger when the Details component is clicked?

Here are the pictures:

[Before Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coVBT.png)

[After Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGhko.png)

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aycL.png)

Comment: Can you provide us with some code to reproduce the problem?